# How to set focus of the window on a sub div of a hidden div?

Tags: javascript

I have two main divs. `div1` is displaying and `div2` is hidden by default.

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

There are two links on the page `Div1` and `Div2`. On clicking Div2, it will hide the `div1` and will show the `div2`.

div2 has several sub divs.

```
<div class="div2">
<div class="sub1"></div>
<div class="sub2" current></div>
<div class="sub3"></div>
</div>
```

The `sub2` div has an extra class of `current`. When I click on the `Div2` link, the `div2` div should show with focus on the div having class `current`.

Comment: What do you mean by "focus" in this case?

Comment: there is a scroll in that div. starting from `sub1`. It should focus on `sub2` div and when I scroll up then the `sub1` should show.

Comment: `div2` is scrollable